# App loading Image

Tags: ios, xcode, image, loading, launch

sometimes when I start my App it shows me a black screen until its loaded.
Where is the place to add an Image or whatever to show that in instead of that nasty black screen?

Thanks in advance,
Philip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black screen simply means that there is no launch image set for your app. The newest and in my opinion easiest way to add these is to use an Asset catalog.

If you created your app in a recent version of xCode, an asset catalog named Images.xcassets is automatically created for you.

Navigate to the same by clicking on it and then simply drag and drop your image into the same.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I would also strongly recommend that you maintain all graphics used in your app via this Asset catalog. The big advantage with using this process is you don't have to worry about the usual naming conventions you would need if you included graphics outside of an asset catalog - for e.g. You no longer have to name retina images as @2x

Comment: thanks! I'm new to app development. much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Something really simple in fact. Go to Xcode, Tap the project on the top, on the drop down menu on the top left select the target, then click General and select images at where it says Launch Images